# Is "about" an adverb 100% of the time if it follows a verb?

Tags: grammar

I thought about was a preposition, but I was told it's an adverb.

> The bridles were lashing about the horses

I hadn't put much thought about it, but now I am confused about how to distinguish the two. So does a preposition modify the preceding noun, and cannot modify anything else? And is "about" an adverb 100% of the time when it follows a verb immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sentence, "They beat him about the head and shoulders." "About" is a preposition. The object of the preposition is "the head and shoulders". The whole prepositional phrase "about the head and shoulders" performs an adverbial function in the sentence (it modifies the verb "beat".)

Now for that sentence *about* [!] those horses: "The bridles were lashing about the horses." Both sentences have a similar structure. "About" is a preposition which is part of a phrase. That phrase acts in an adverbial function within the sentence. But the word "about" isn't an adverb in either sentence.

I see that J.R. made the assertion (in answer to an earlier question about this same sentence) that, according to Wordnik, "about" was an adverb.

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/about) lists "about" as *either* an adverb *or* a preposition depending on the situation.

> prep. On all sides of; surrounding
>
> adv. All around; on every side

"About" is an adverb when it doesn't have any objects following it.

Examples of  adverbial "about": "When we took the fish off the hook, it thrashed about."; "The horses were galloping, and the loose reins were lashing about."; "Confused, he blinked and looked about."

"About" followed by a noun is usually a preposition, and that noun is its object. Examples: "Confused, he blinked and looked about *him*."; or "The reins (or *bridles*) were lashing about *the horses*."

If "about" were an adverb in the horse-sentence, then the two words at the end, "the horses", would have no function in the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought too, but the answer got upvoted.